# Reloading TTF_Font* for just changing pointsize using TTF_OpenFontRW?

Tags: c++, performance, sdl, truetype

I want to be ablte to dynamically resize the text that I rendered to the screen with my TTF_Font* object. The way I am doing it right now is, I close the font

```
TTF_CloseFont(font);
```

and then just open it right after using the new point size

```
font = TTF_OpenFont(filepath, new_pointsize);
```

Now my question is, is this the efficient way to do things? Does that mean that every time I reload my font, changing the pointsize, I delete the in-memory structure of my font and then a new one is created meaning I read the whole file from disk again?

Now in order to make it more efficient, I would like to keep my .ttf-file in memory somehow and just change the size of it. Is that possible?

I was trying to do something with `SDL_RWops` but I didn't succeed. Here is what I did in my `load` function:

```
font_rw = SDL_RWFromFile(filepath, "r");
font = TTF_OpenFontRW(font_rw, 0, pointsize);
```

and in my `reload` function:

```
TTF_CloseFont(font);
font = TTF_OpenFontRW(font_rw, 0, pointsize);
```

Now the problem is, that the font is not being loaded correctly, so I get NULL back as the return value for the `TTF_OpenFontRW` in `reload`.

Comment: @keltar Why answer in a comment?  Add some paragraphs and that is an acceptable answer.

Comment: I edited the question to now be more precise and with more focus on the solution using SDL_RWops.

Comment: Did you rewind the `SDL_RWops` back to the beginning of the file via `SDL_RWseek(font_rw, 0, RW_SEEK_SET)`?

Comment: @genpfault That worked! Thanks. I am not sure how SDL_RW handles the file internally though. Now that the code works, is this even the desired behaviour? Because I call SDL_RWFromFile once, I hope to read from disk only once, and from then on, I use the already existing in-memory structure font_rw, correct?

Comment: Check [the implementation of `SDL_RWFromFile()`](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/56d508cebb46/src/file/SDL_rwops.c#l508).  Looks like it uses native Windows file I/O on Windows; you'd be at the mercy of the block/filesystem cache re: file re-reads.  Only way to guarantee no re-reads is to read the font file into memory yourself and pass it off to `SDL_RWFromMem()`.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you very much.